# looping a gsub to pull from hana based on a table of values

Tags: r, loops, lapply, gsub

I hope my title makes sense! If not feel free to edit it.

I have a table in R that contains unique dates. Sometimes this table may have one date at other times it may have multiple dates .I would like to loop these unique dates into SQL query I have created to pull data and append to px_tbl. I am at a loss however where to start. Below is what I have so far and obviously works when I have only 1 unique date however when the table contains 2 dates it doesn't pull.

```
unique_dates_df
DATE
2016-12-15
2017-02-15
2017-03-02
2017-03-09

sqlCMD_px <- 'SELECT *
           FROM "_SYS_BIC"."My.Table/PRICE"
           (\'PLACEHOLDER\' = (\'$$P_EFF_DATE$$\',\'%D\'))'

sqlCMD_px <- gsub("%D", unique_dates_tbl, sqlCMD_px)##<- the gsub is needed
so that the dates are formatted correctly for the SQL pull

px_tbl <- sqlQuery(myconn, sqlCMD_px)
```

I am convinced that an apply function will work in one form or another but haven't been able to figure it out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
#SQL command template
sqlCmdTemp <- 'SELECT *
           FROM '_SYS_BIC'.'My.Table/PRICE'
           (\'PLACEHOLDER\' = (\'$$P_EFF_DATE$$\',\'%D\'))'

#Dates as character
unique_dates <- c("2017-03-08","2017-03-09", "2017-03-10")

#sapply command
res<-sapply(unique_dates, function(d) { sqlQuery(conn, gsub("%D",d,sqlCmdTemp))},simplify=F)

#bind rows
tbl.df<-do.call(rbind,res)
```

Comment: Hi Marcello - unique_dates is actually a data frame and when I tried to use the data frame I get the below error. 'argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used'

Comment: @mannym, if there is only one column in the data frame, you can use unique_dates[,1] instead of just unique_dates.

Comment: I tried that and it worked. I will update my question and edit your answer. Thanks again for your help!